# Django and SinglePageApp : how to use django static auth

Tags: django

I would like to have a Django Backend to handle Login : it would be a classic template generated from Django. The main difference is that once the user is logged in, I want django to redirect him to a Single Page App (page served by nginx or an other component but not by Django).

The idea is to have one git repo for my backend, and one git repo for my frontend. I don't want to mix Django templating with my Javascript App (ie AngularJS or React).

Is it possible to proceed like this ? (The main idea is to prevent users who can't login to have access to the SPA app.js file, this file will not be accessible from the classic template django login page)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly the whole issue but if you just want to prevent unlogged visitors to come to a specific view (page) :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def access_limited_page(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        # Forced Redirection
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
    else:
        # Welcome to the VIP zone
        …
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to the url of your Single Page App. Then just use standard login view from django.

While user logged in, django will redirect to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.

Comment: I'll try this. In production I will use Nginx in front of Django and my SPA. In dev env, what is the best solution to achieve this ? (If I use django dev server and a gulp server for my SPA I'll have CORS issues)